# Criteria mentioned in model class not executing from search form

Tags: php, yii-extensions, yii

I have two fields in the advanced search form(approved, reviewdate) for which I  created the radiobuttons.

```
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,''); ?>
<?php
    echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'ReviewedDate',
    array('1' => 'Reviewed', '' => 'Not Reviewed'),
    array(
          'template'=>'{input}{label}',
          'separator'=>'',
          'labelOptions'=>array(
                        'style'=> '
                                  padding-left:13px;
                                  width: 60px;
                                  float: left;
                                 '),
          'onclick' => 'this.form.submit()', 
          'style'=>'float:left;',
          )                             
      );
        ?>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'ReviewedDate'); ?>
 </div>


   <div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,''); ?>
<?php
    echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'Approved',
    array('0' => 'Rejected', '1' => 'Approved'),
    array(
          'template'=>'{input}{label}',
          'separator'=>'',
          'labelOptions'=>array(
                        'style'=> '
                                  padding-left:13px;
                                  width: 60px;
                                  float: left;
                                 '),
          'style'=>'float:left;',
          'onclick' => 'this.form.submit()', 
          'uncheck' => NULL,
          )                             
      );
        ?>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'Approved'); ?>
 </div>
```

Below is the criteria I created for both the fields in model.

```
public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
                $criteria->with=array('apartment');
        $criteria->compare('t.Id',$this->Id);
        $criteria->compare('ApartmentId',$this->ApartmentId);
        $criteria->compare('Approved',$this->Approved);
        $criteria->compare('CreatedDate',$this->CreatedDate,true);
        $criteria->compare('EmailBody',$this->EmailBody,true);
        $criteria->compare('MailSubject',$this->MailSubject,true);
                $criteria->compare('MessageType',1);
        $criteria->compare('Name',$this->Name,true);
  //              $criteria->compare('ReviewedDate',$this->ReviewedDate);

                        $criteria->compare('SmsText',$this->SmsText,true);
            $criteria->compare('UpdatedDate',$this->UpdatedDate,true);
        $criteria->compare('PostedByUserFlatId',$this->PostedByUserFlatId);
        $criteria->compare('Comments',$this->Comments,true);
        $criteria->compare('ModifiedBy',$this->ModifiedBy,true);


                if(isset($this->ReviewedDate) )
                {

                $criteria->addCondition('ReviewedDate IS NOT NULL');
                $criteria->addCondition('UpdatedDate > CreatedDate');
                $criteria->compare('ReviewedDate','0000-00-00 00:00:00');

                }
                else 
                {
                $criteria->addCondition('updateddate = createddate');    
                $criteria->addCondition('ReviewedDate IS NULL');

                } 


                if ($this->Approved) 
               {

                      $criteria->addCondition("approved='" . $this->Approved . "'");
                      $criteria->condition = ' (updateddate > createddate) AND (revieweddate IS NOT NULL) and approved = 1 ';
                }
                else 
                {

                      $criteria->addCondition("approved='" . $this->Approved . "'");
                      $criteria->condition = ' (updateddate > createddate) AND (revieweddate IS NOT NULL) and approved = 0 ';
                }

                $criteria->compare('apartment.Name',$this->groupz_search, true);
                $criteria->compare('apartment.SocietyCode',$this->groupz_code_search, true);
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
```

Now when I try click on the reviewed/not reviewed button, the query that should be executed when rejected is clicked gets executed.

```
SQL query to be executed - SELECT count(*) FROM `message_template` `t`  LEFT OUTER JOIN `apartment` `apartment` ON (`t`.`ApartmentId`=`apartment`.`Id`)  WHERE (((MessageType=1) AND (updateddate = createddate)) AND (ReviewedDate IS NULL);


SQL executed - SELECT * FROM `message_template` `t`  LEFT OUTER JOIN `apartment` `apartment` ON (`t`.`ApartmentId`=`apartment`.`Id`)  WHERE (((MessageType=1) AND (updateddate > createddate)) AND (ReviewedDate IS NULL) and (Approved=0));
```

Why is this happening and how can I debug.

**Edit**
**Controller**

```
<?php

class MessageTemplateController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
     * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
     */
    public $layout='//layouts/column2';

    /**
     * @return array action filters
     */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        );
    }

    /**
     * Specifies the access control rules.
     * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
     * @return array access control rules
     */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
#               'users'=>array('admin'),
                                'users'=>array('@'),//vishnu
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a particular model.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
               // $model = MessageTemplate::model()->findByPk($id);
                $model = $this->loadModel($id);
        $this->render('view', array(
                'model' => $model,                      
        ));

    }

    /**
     * Creates a new model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new MessageTemplate;


        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['MessageTemplate']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['MessageTemplate'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->Id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        )

             );

    }

    /**
     * Updates a particular model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {       
                $model_mt=new Messagesintable;   
                $model_al=new AuditLogin;                
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

                 if(isset($_POST['MessageTemplate']) && isset($_POST['AuditLogin']))
                  {                     


                    $model->attributes=$_POST['MessageTemplate'];                                      

                    list($name,$mobile,$email)=retrieve_persondetails($id); 

                      if($model->save())
                      {
                        $model_al->attributes=$_POST['AuditLogin'];                     


                        if($model->Approved==1)                        
                        {   
                        if($name!=NULL)
                        {     
                        $model_mt->Address= address_xml($name, $mobile, $email);
                        $message=$model->SmsText;
                        $approved="-approved";
                        $model_mt->Message= message_xml($message,$approved);
                        $model_mt->MsgType=1;
                        $model_mt->Date=date('Y-m-d');
                        $model_mt->Time=date('H:i:s');
                        $model_mt->CustomData='0,0';
                        $model_mt->save();
                        }
                        $model_al->activity="Message Template Approved";
                        $model_al->moduleId=1003; 
                        $model_al->content=$model->SmsText;
                        }
                        else 
                        { 
                        if($name!=NULL)
                        {    
                        $model_mt->Address= address_xml($name, $mobile, $email);
                        $message=$model->SmsText;
                        $approved="-rejected";
                        $model_mt->Message= message_xml($message,$approved);
                        $model_mt->MsgType=1;
                        $model_mt->Date=date('Y-m-d');
                        $model_mt->Time=date('H:i:s');
                        $model_mt->CustomData='0,0';
                        $model_mt->save();   
                        }
                        $model_al->activity="Message Template Rejected";
                        $model_al->moduleId=1003; 
                        $model_al->content=$model->SmsText;
                        }
                     if ($model_al->save())
                         $this->redirect(array('admin','id'=>$model->Id));
                      }
                  }
$this->render('update',array(
'model'=>$model,

)); 
}

    /**
     * Deletes a particular model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }

    /**
     * Lists all models.
    */ 
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('MessageTemplate');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,

        ));

}

// Oh yeah the filter. I just copied your code.
/*

*/



    /**
     * Manages all models.
     */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new MessageTemplate('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['MessageTemplate']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['MessageTemplate'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));

    }

    /**
     * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
     * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
     * @return MessageTemplate the loaded model
     * @throws CHttpException
     */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=MessageTemplate::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }



    /**
     * Performs the AJAX validation.
     * @param MessageTemplate $model the model to be validated
     */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='message-template-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}

        function retrieve_persondetails($id)
       {
          $hostname="localhost";
          $username=Yii::app()->db->username;
          $password=Yii::app()->db->password;
          $database="apartment";
          $connection = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
          mysql_select_db($database);
          $sql = "SELECT p.Name,p.Mobile,p.Email from person p,flat f,userflatmapping u,message_template m, society_profile s where m.id=$id and u.id=m.postedbyuserflatid and f.id=u.flatid and p.id=f.registeredpersonid and u.dontsendsmstome=0 and s.apartmentId=f.apartmentid and s.sms_enabled=1;";
          $result = mysql_query($sql);
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
            $name=$row['Name'];
            $mobile=$row['Mobile'];
            $email=$row['Email']; 
           }
           if(isset($name))
          return array($name,$mobile,$email);
          mysql_close($connection);
         }


        function address_xml($name,$mobile,$email)
  {

$address_xml = '<tolist><to><name>' . $name . '</name><contactpersonname>' . $name  . '</contactpersonname><number>' . $mobile  . '</number><email>' . $email . '</email><prefix></prefix><contactpersonprefix></contactpersonprefix></to></tolist><from><name>' . $name . '</name><number>' . $mobile . '</number></from>';
return $address_xml;
  }

  function message_xml($message,$approved)
  {
$message_xml ='<shorttext>' . $message.''.$approved. '</shorttext>';
return $message_xml;
  }
```

**edit rules**

```
public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('ApartmentId, Approved, MessageType, PostedByUserFlatId', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('Name, SmsText, Comments, ModifiedBy', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            array('CreatedDate, EmailBody, MailSubject, ReviewedDate, UpdatedDate', 'safe'),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('Id, ApartmentId, Approved, CreatedDate, EmailBody, MailSubject, MessageType, Name, ReviewedDate, SmsText, UpdatedDate, PostedByUserFlatId, Comments, ModifiedBy,apartment.Name,apartment.SocietyCode,groupz_search,groupz_code_search', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
                        //array('ReviewedDate','default',
              //'value'=>new CDbExpression('NOW()'),
              //'setOnEmpty'=>false,'on'=>'update'),
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us also your controller code?

Comment: @davey I pasted my controller

Comment: Can you also post your rules() method in your model?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$criteria->condition = '';` after calling `$criteria->addCondition();`

With `$criteria->condition = '';` you set a whole new condition for the CDbCriteria object, which means all your previous `$criteria->addCondition();` are lost.

So change this, for example:

```
$criteria->addCondition("approved='" . $this->Approved . "'");
$criteria->condition = ' (updateddate > createddate) AND (revieweddate IS NOT NULL) and approved = 0 ';
```

To this:

```
$criteria->addCondition("approved='" . $this->Approved . "'");
$criteria->addCondition("(updateddate > createddate) AND (revieweddate IS NOT NULL)");
```

Comment: This displays a diffrent query

Comment: SQL - SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`Id`)
FROM `message_template` `t`  LEFT OUTER JOIN `apartment` `apartment` ON
(`t`.`ApartmentId`=`apartment`.`Id`)  WHERE (((((MessageType=:ycp0) AND
(updateddate = createddate)) AND (ReviewedDate IS NULL)) AND (approved=''))
AND ((updateddate > createddate) AND (revieweddate IS NOT NULL) AND
approved = 0))

Answer (score 0):

This code is almost right:

```
if ($this->Approved) 
           {

                  $criteria->addCondition("approved='" . $this->Approved . "'");
                  $criteria->condition = ' (updateddate > createddate) AND (revieweddate IS NOT NULL) and approved = 1 ';
            }
            else 
            {

                  $criteria->addCondition("approved='" . $this->Approved . "'");
                  $criteria->condition = ' (updateddate > createddate) AND (revieweddate IS NOT NULL) and approved = 0 ';
            }
```

As "davey" says you must "clean up" your search function, and for example you might change you code like this:

```
if ($this->Approved) 
           {
           //this line is unnecessary     $criteria->addCondition("approved='" . $this->Approved . "'");
                  $criteria->addCondition(' (updateddate > createddate) AND (revieweddate IS NOT NULL) and approved = 1 ');
            }
            else 
            {
            //this line is unnecessary      $criteria->addCondition("approved='" . $this->Approved . "'");
                 $criteria->addCondition(' (updateddate > createddate) AND (revieweddate IS NOT NULL) and approved = 0 ');

       //if you dont want   approved = 0 then you must change above line with:
                  $criteria->addCondition(' (updateddate > createddate) AND (revieweddate IS NOT NULL) ');



            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug:

first are you sure your send the form params by GET?

```
<form action="/controller/action" method="get">
```

second for testing your values I would do something like this:

```
if(isset($this->Approved)){
  if($this->Approved==0){
    ...
  }elseif($this->Approved==1){
    ...
  }else{
    throw new CHttpExeption(404,'unknown approval');
  }
}
```

so if nothing is submitted -> no criteria will be added

Hope this helps

Best regards